# 「佑里子は私にを教えてくれました」and「私は佑里子のかくせいです」

Tags: english-to-japanese, sentence

Would 佑里子は私にを教えてくれました mean "Yuriko taught me"? Am I saying it correctly and using correct grammar? Otherwise, how would it be best to say "Yuriko taught me. She's a good teacher"

Would it make sense if I said "I am Yuriko's student", could I use 私は佑里子のかくせいです?

Comment: Where did you find the first sentence? Particularly, what is the combination にを?

Comment: `how would it be best to say "Yuriko taught me.` >> I think we usually say 「(私は)(～～に)[教]{おそ}わりました」(http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E6%95%99%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%22) , [習]{なら}いました or maybe [教]{おし}えてもらいました

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you wrote, but it's not using correct grammar.

- You should have an honorific (such as "san" or "sensei").
- *ni* and *wo* don't go together
- The verb *oshieru* takes an object (to teach *something*). Out of context, it feels weird.
- I think *ga* is better than *ha* for this sentence

Regarding the second sentence, the word for student is "gakusei", not "kakusei". You still need the honorific.